# What is "sedCh0n6k"?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

Something weird appears when I click on Tow icon to open browser: an icon with binary numbers, a lock and an X appears. the icon's name is "sedCh0n6k". What is it? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This is a temporary file left behind by the `sed` command-line utility.

`sed` describes itself as *"a stream editor"*, saying *"A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file or input from  a  pipeline)"*. It's often used in shell scripts for searching and replacing text and similar operations on text files.

`sed` is used in a few places in the `start-tor-browser` shell script which sets up the environment for Tor Browser to run properly before launching `firefox`.

Normally `sed` should be cleaning this up after it has finished processing the file by renaming it to the original file.

```
$ echo 'foo' > test # create a simple text file
$ strace -e open,rename sed -i 's/foo/bar/' test # trace the calls to 'open' and 'rename' that sed makes
[ ... unimportant syscalls ... ]
open("test", O_RDONLY)                  = 3
open("./sed2WewTJ", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
rename("./sed2WewTJ", "test")           = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`sed` created a new file called `sed2WewTJ` (the prefix being `sed` and the suffix `2WewTJ` being random) then once it's done operating on the file it renames the file to `test` to replace the original file with the newly edited file, to avoid directly operating on the original file.